# Bike parking in Kyoto

Tags: japan, bicycles, kyoto

If I rent a bike for sightseeing, is there any parking space to leave it near temples, shrines, markets, etc. (Kinkakuji, Fushimi Inari, Nishiki, Gion...)? Is it safe?

Comment: We stayed in an AirBNB in Kyoto that had bicycles and we used them to get around town and sightseeing. I don't recall ever having a "parking" problem. Every place we visited had either a dedicated or a natural spot to leave & lock your bikes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple Google search for "京都 駐輪場" (Kyoto bike parking lots) brought me to [this page](https://kyoto-bicycle.com/parking), which contains all city government-approved bike parking lots. Most of them are cheap (150-300 yen per day), and many of them offer 3 hour free parking. But unfortunately, this page is in Japanese, and the English language version of this website doesn't contain a lot of info about parking.

But then you could always find your destination on Google Maps, click "nearby", and search for "bike parking". If you see 自転車駐車場 or 駐輪場, then it's a bike parking place. There's also an English language site [here](http://kanko.city.kyoto.lg.jp/bicycle/en/parking/) if you're too lazy to Google.

As for safety, I believe Kyoto is a rather safe place. Of course, you should bring your chain lock or U-lock, and lock up your bike. Do NOT park on the streets as it is illegal in Kyoto; your bike will be towed away. Not a pleasant situation.

Comment: +1 (but I had to smile on a bike being 'towed'.) One small question, are we talking motor bike or push bike here?

Comment: @Willeke push bikes also, the city regularly removes illegally parked according to https://www.insidekyoto.com/cycling-kyoto

Comment: The main temples had free parking areas nearby.