Parking a bike in Kyoto in front of temples
I'm planning a trip to Japan next year - Tokyo, Osaka and Kyoto.
We would like to rent a bike in Kyoto, can you tell me your experience with parking them in front of temples?
I assumed there was a dedicated parking spot; I was just wondering if they exist close to attractions. We were planning to spend three days in Kyoto, and when researching, I came across a video mentioning renting a bike. It sounded like a good idea to make the most of our time.

Bicycle or motorcycle?

related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115181/bike-parking-in-kyoto

You should check where you park in order to avoid fines.
From this site:

Bicycle parking is illegal on Kyoto’s streets.
Please do not park your bicycle anywhere on Kyoto streets outside of designated parking lots (marked on the map).
Bicycles parked illegally will be removed and the owner (or renter) will be charged 2,300 JPY (Nov 2024: about €13.87) to have it returned.
For information on bicycle rental shops and bicycle parking lots:
https://kyoto-bicycle.com/en/rental_search

Out of personal experience, when cycling in Kyoto years ago I crossed over a railway bridge on my bike. I failed to see the sign that it was forbidden for bikes. Before I reached the end of it I had a police car behind me flashing its lights and stopping me at the side of the road. Then I got questioned and my documents checked.
Japan is generally a safe country, but this means the police has time to go after infractions which in other countries would get a shoulder shrug from law enforcement.

and of course one reason it is a safe country is because the police tend to be alert and active.

Usually, you cannot park in front of temples, shops, etc. It will surely lead to complaints and likely your bike will be towed. In the unlikely case that there is a bicycle parking space on the sidewalk near the temple, feel free to do so, but I'm afraid you'd have to find the closest bicycle parking lot. Fortunately, most tourist spots have parking lots for bicycles, some free, and some are tolled (but usually cheap).
Do NOT park in convenience stores' or apartment/office buildings' parking lots, as this is considered trespassing and will lead to all kinds of trouble. If you are just parking for 5 minutes I guess no one would care, but if you're going to park longer, go find a parking spot.
If you mean a motorcycle, then you need to find a motorcycle parking lot (usually within an automobile parking lot). Don't ever park anywhere else. You'll get caught and be fined.
